# Comparison between FEM libraries & languages

Tags: finite-element, reference-request

Is there any modern online resources which compares the most popular finite element method libraries/packages/languages?

Answer (score 3):

This is the best resource that I know: https://github.com/kostyfisik/FEA-compare